# for each loop @object and getting @object.attribute not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, object, attributes, for-loop

Im trying to for each loop true @participants collection like below:

```
- (1..@participants.count).each do |participant|
    - @user = User.where(:id => 1).first
    # @user = User.where(:id => particpant.id).first ==> throws error: ...
    # (undefined method `id' for 1:Fixnum):
    #participants
      #block
        #image
          = show_avatar(@user.id)
          #name
            = @user.username
```

Confused on how to get the participant.id value for each looped object, cannot figure out how to after searched for a solution. Should I use a render collection instead or is there a way to get the participant.id for each looped participant? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to create a range, you can do the following, if participants is an array of participant objects:

```
- @participants.each do |participant|
  - user = User.where(:id => participant.id).first
```

It's even better to setup a rails relation.

```
class Participant
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This way you can simply do `participant.user`

I can't tell you how to setup those relations specifically because you did not give enough details. But this should get you started.